# Jquery scrollTo not working: object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: jquery, scrollto

Hello I have included the jquery-1.5.1.min.js and jquery.scrollTo-min.js scripts into my page. I've setup the anchor tags seemingly appropriately, but when I click on one of the anchors I get the error mentioned above. Here's some code I've tried.

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#midGrids').scrollTo('#avgSpreadGroupGridHere', 800);">Avg Spread</a>
<a href="#" onclick="$.scrollTo('#avgSpreadGroupGridHere', 800);">Avg Spread</a>
<a href="#" onclick="$(...).scrollTo('#avgSpreadGroupGridHere', 800);">Avg Spread</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you named your target id to: "#midGrids" ?

you have to do something like this:

```
<a href="#" id="target">Target</a>

<a href="#" onclick="$(...).scrollTo('#target', 800);">Avg Spread</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. My target is avgSpreadGroupGridHere, that's what I would like to scroll to. As for midGrids that's the div I would like to do the actual scroll. When I look at Ariel's demo code I can see that he uses the anchor title to place his code into. But that does not work for my either. So I think I'm having some kind of base config issue. Like are there some other prereqs I need to get this thing to work. The error seems to indicate that. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you try to include the init.js :D ? he included it in his example page but I don't think this is the problem... (you still can try that)

Comment: what is this file. where do i get it

Comment: I've got it by viewing the source of the html page :D, here is it http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/js/init.js

Comment: I tried adding the init.js file, but that gives me an error that I'm trying to link to Flesler's scripts and sends me to this link http://code.google.com/p/flesler-plugins/downloads/list